# How to edit /etc/fstab if it in ro mode?

Tags: fstab, 18.10

Me set "data=journal" in etc/fstab file, after that i reboot, but system doesn't booting. After that me boot from LIVE-CD and tried to delete "data=journal" from /etc/fstab, but file works in ro mode.

blkid & /dev/disk/*:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="5aab4fef-bdbd-4f6f-bf59-7c164354a8fa" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="93d3e9f3-01"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2018-10-17-22-44-30-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 18.10 amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="133f436e" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 10 16:17 ata-VBOX_CD-ROM_VB2-01700376 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 10 16:17 ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB78947f38-edb217dd -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 10 16:19 ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB78947f38-edb217dd-part1 -> ../../sda1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 10 16:17 2018-10-17-22-44-30-00 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 10 16:19 5aab4fef-bdbd-4f6f-bf59-7c164354a8fa -> ../../sda1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 10 16:17 'Ubuntu\x2018.10\x20amd64' -> ../../sr0
```

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen thx man! lower you can watch how i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd /media/ubuntu/
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu$ ls
5aab4fef-bdbd-4f6f-bf59-7c164354a8fa
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu$ cd 5aab4fef-bdbd-4f6f-bf59-7c164354a8fa/
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/5aab4fef-bdbd-4f6f-bf59-7c164354a8fa$ ls
bin    etc             lib         mnt   run   swapfile  var
boot   home            lib64       opt   sbin  sys       vmlinuz
cdrom  initrd.img      lost+found  proc  snap  tmp       vmlinuz.old
dev    initrd.img.old  media       root  srv   usr
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/5aab4fef-bdbd-4f6f-bf59-7c164354a8fa$ cd etc/
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/5aab4fef-bdbd-4f6f-bf59-7c164354a8fa/etc$ sudo nano fstab
```

It's solution!